# How to pass a file name into a function using shell script?

Tags: linux, function, shell, unix

I have a requirement where I need to pass a file into a function. Here is my function

```
rec(){
mapfile -t rect < $f
echo ${rect[2]}
}

f=$(< file1.txt)
rec $f
```

But this is not working. 
I get the below error

```
   ./test.sh: line 2: $f: ambiguous redirect
```

Do you know where I am going wrong?

Comment: Why not just `f="file1.txt"`? Also you should quote your variables when passing them so they are all nice and encapsulated `rec "$f"` Lastly, the first parameter (your filename) is going to be stored in `$1` not in `$f` inside the function.

Comment: @JNevill, it worked!!! Thanks a lot.